# validation using ng-class not working

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-class

In my application until all the mandatory fields are filled the update billing button doesn't get enabled. Here i have used ng-class for this validation. But rather than the button remain disabled until i fill mandatory field, it shows the error message as "message webpage: [object] [Object]" Any help?

```
  @if (HttpContext.Current.Session["RoleID"].ToString() == "3")
                                                {
                                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-lg-2 pull-left">Quality<span class="Imp">*</span></label>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-8">

                                                                <select id="Quality" disabled="disabled" name="Quality" class="form-control" style="width:170px" tooltip="Quality is required"
                                                                        tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter">
                                                                    <option value="default">Choose here</option>
                                                                    <option value="Satisfactory">Satisfactory</option>
                                                                    <option value="NotSatisfactory">Not Satisfactory</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                }

                                                else
                                                {
                                                    <div class="form-horizontal" ng-class="{'has-error':EditOCBForm.Quality.$invalid &&
                                                  EditOCBForm.Cycle.$dirty}">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label col-lg-2 pull-left">Quality<span class="Imp">*</span></label>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                                                <select id="Quality" name="Quality" class="form-control" style="width:170px" ng-model="vm.EditRef_OCBUI.Quality" tooltip="Quality is required"
                                                                        tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" required="required">
                                                                    <option value="Satisfactory">Satisfactory</option>
                                                                    <option value="NotSatisfactory">Not Satisfactory</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                }
```

button code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="Edit()" ng-disabled="EditOCBForm.$invalid" id="ticketEditbtn">Update Billing</button>
```

Comment: what does `EditOCBForm.$invalid` gives your

Comment: the button should be disabled but even though i am leaving the field blank the button gets enabled and on clicking I am getting the object object error message

Comment: you have missed the required  tag for 1st input .. mark as excepted if the answer helped @beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed `required` tag in 1st input

```
 <select id="Quality" disabled="disabled" name="Quality" class="form-control" 
     style="width:170px" tooltip="Quality is required" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" required >

       <option value="default">Choose here</option>
       <option value="Satisfactory">Satisfactory</option>
      <option value="NotSatisfactory">Not Satisfactory</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Try with this and mark as excepted if this helped @beginner

Comment: but the if statement is to disable the partiular field. Its  not "required" to be filled. So you mean with ng-class validation i have to use required?

Comment: yes .. if that input is comes up it will not be required which will make the field valid

Comment: but Now for the if statment i have remove the ng class and even removed required tag. Still I am getting the error "object object"

Comment: what does  `EditOCBForm.Quality.$invalid` gives you

Comment: Actually when the quality field is empty the update billing button should not be enabled at all but here its enabled even though the quality field is empty. It gives the error pop up "Message webpage: object oject]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138009/discussion-between-beginner-and-boss).

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use form?

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.list.name" required>

  <div class="alert alert-danger ng-if="!formName.name.$valid">
    <p>The field is required</p>            
  </div>

  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!formName.$valid">Save</button>
</form>
```